# How to find the minimum value of the given modulus equation using traingle inequality

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, absolute-value

My question is to find the minimum value of
$$|x-1|+|3x-1|+|5x-1|+|7x-1|+|9x-1|+|11x-1|$$
One way is to find the minimum value using graph by which I got the answer $X=\frac{1}{9}$

But I want to know a simpler way to do it and for it I tried solving it using traingle inequality but wasn't getting the right answer so can anyone provide any simpler method or provide explanation how to solve using traingle inequality

Comment: How do you get $\frac 19$ as a value?  Even $|x-1|+|3x-1|$ can't get that small.

Comment: Note:  the word is "triangle"  not traingle.

Comment: Oh, did you mean that the minimum value is realized at $f\left(\frac 19\right)$?  That makes sense.  It's natural to look at the places one or another of the absolute values vanishes.  The minimum will be realized at one of those.

Comment: It is a convex piecewise linear function with breakpoints at $1,1/3,\ldots,1/11$, so it will be one of them. You can find it by hand or find the point where the two pieces meeting at the breakpoint have opposite monotonicity by seeing when the coefficient at $x$ changes from negative to positive as you "open" the absolute values.

Comment: When $x$ is between $1/7$ and $1/5$, you can work out all the absolute values, and get $(1-x)+(1-3x)+(1-5x)+(7x-1)+(9x-1)+(11x-1)=18x$ so the minimum, for that interval at least, is at the least value of $x$, which is $x=1/7$.  Repeat for other key intervals

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4750026/how-to-find-minimum-value-of-given-multiple-modulus-function